# Read cookie value with c#

Tags: c#, cookies, webforms

using asp.net/c#, how is possible to :

- display a webform only when the cookie value has been set to "1". (on page_load event)
  So the asp code should just read the cookie value and make visible/invisible the webform

Note that the cookie value I will set it with php.
Note that the html webform is included in the code:

asp:Content ID="webform" ContentPlaceHolderID="webform1" runat="Server"

So I need a way to manipulate this webform depending of the settings of the cookie value that I will read all the time the page gets loaded

Comment: and the code is ? :)

Comment: sorry. I edited for mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (!Page.IsPostback)

Call the method below, based on the return value response.redirect to another page.

```
private string GetCookieValue(string cookieName, string itemName)
{
    var CookieName = "MY_COOKIE";
    var CookieValue = string.empty;

    HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies[CookieName];
    if (myCookie == null) return "No cookie found";

    //If you added a key vs. the value in the cookie use this code
    //CookieValue = myCookie[itemName].ToString();

    //Get the value of the cookie if you are not using a key
    CookieValue = myCookie.Value.ToString();

    Return CookieValue;
}
```

Comment: question 1: so I don't have to touch the method page_load?

Comment: question 2: where you set the condition of the pop up displaying if cookie is set or not?